# Checking parameter types in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to check the type of my params in my React/Typescript component

```
foo(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement> | React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>) {
    if(e is mouse event) {
        //do something
    }
    else if (e is KeyboardEvent) {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

How can I write the if/else conditions?

Comment: Might it be easier to register different handlers for mouse and keyboard events, and then you won't have to switch on the event type at all?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of event.type property.
for more detail explanation please refer these docs [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)

Comment: Combined with type-guards this would be more typescript oriented, but definitely a good way to check :)

Comment: i tried `if(e.type ===  React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>)` but it throws the error `e.type ===  React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>`

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty it's not a type in the typescript sense of the word, it's a string

Comment: so `event.type` alone can't do what im trying to achieve?

Comment: It can in conjunction with type guards :)  `type` can be either of these strings for mouse events: `onClick onContextMenu onDoubleClick onDrag onDragEnd onDragEnter onDragExit
onDragLeave onDragOver onDragStart onDrop onMouseDown onMouseEnter onMouseLeave
onMouseMove onMouseOut onMouseOver onMouseUp`  https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty what I say in my answer still holds, about types being erased and having to test with properties, this is arguably a more precise way to identify the type

Answer (score 1):

`React.MouseEvent` and `React.KeyboardEvent` are both defined as interfaces and thus there is no runtime representation for these types. We can create a type-guard to differentiate between the types, and we can use properties defined on the object actually test  if the object conforms to the interface:

```
function isMouseEvent<T>(e: any | React.MouseEvent<T>) : e is React.MouseEvent<T> {
    let eMouse = e as React.MouseEvent<T>;
    // Can test for other properties as well
    return eMouse && typeof eMouse.pageX === "number" && typeof eMouse.pageY === "number"
}

function isKeyboardEvent<T>(e: any | React.KeyboardEvent<T>) : e is React.KeyboardEvent<T> {
    let eKey= e as React.KeyboardEvent<T>;
    // Can test for other properties as well
    return eKey&& typeof eKey.charCode === "number" && typeof eKey.key === "string"
}

function foo(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement> | React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>) {
    if(isMouseEvent(e)) {
        e // will be React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>
    }
    else {
        e // will be React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLElement> by exclusion, or we could use the other type guard
    }
}
```